# Get only the first objects of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hello i have an object in JavaScript which contains this:

```
{Coc Coc={30daysAgo=1}, Mozilla={30daysAgo=1}, BlackBerry={30daysAgo=1}, Safari={30daysAgo=140}, Firefox={30daysAgo=192}, YaBrowser={30daysAgo=6}, Internet Explorer={30daysAgo=72}, Safari (in-app)={30daysAgo=40}, Android Browser={30daysAgo=3}, Chrome={30daysAgo=1387}, SeaMonkey={30daysAgo=1}, Edge={30daysAgo=7}, Opera={30daysAgo=7}}
```

How can i insert in a variable only the names of the browsers without the rest?

e.g var browsers = Mozilla,BlackBerry,Safari etc...

Comment: that is not a valid object syntax, please reformat your code to be understandable.

Comment: There is no "first" in an object, and you don't have an object ?

Comment: this is not a javascript object, javascript objects looks like this `{Mozilla:{whatever}}`

Comment: Which criterion should be used to ignore "Coc Coc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = {"Coc Coc":{"30daysAgo":1}, Mozilla:{"30daysAgo":1}, BlackBerry:{"30daysAgo":1}, Safari:{"30daysAgo":140}, Firefox:{"30daysAgo":192}, YaBrowser:{"30daysAgo":6}, "Internet Explorer":{"30daysAgo":72}, "Safari (in-app)":{"30daysAgo":40}, "Android Browser":{"30daysAgo":3}, Chrome:{"30daysAgo":1387}, SeaMonkey:{"30daysAgo":1}, Edge:{"30daysAgo":7}, Opera:{"30daysAgo":7}};

var browsers = Object.keys(a).join(",");
```

Result:

> Coc Coc,Mozilla,BlackBerry,Safari,Firefox,YaBrowser,Internet Explorer,Safari (in-app),Android Browser,Chrome,SeaMonkey,Edge,Opera

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m35tL8ms/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer!